# Clip raster tool with polygon will not clip raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, clip

[image]I am trying clip a raster with a polygon (500 meter buffers around point data). The reason why I want the clip is because I want to analyze the information in the clips using the zonal statistics tool. When I run the clip raster tool it appears to be working (no error messages) but the output is not clipped - it is just the same old raster that I am starting with?

Comment: If the output is on the right, that looks clipped to me. Although it's hard to tell at such a far out zoom. You also don't need to do a separate clip to make Zonal Statistics work. Just include your buffered points layer as the Zone Layer.

Comment: Thank you - the clip on the right are just the buffered zones not clipped raster. I just edited it so you can see what I am trying to clip instead. I have many polygons that are clipping the raster.  I tried using zonal statistics without clipping but I want the majority land use in EACH clipped zone and the output with zonal statistics seem to be TOTAL values and areas - but I need the raster info for each clipped zone...

Answer (score 0):

@ycartwhelen is correct, you do not have to clip the raster to zonal statistics. What I was doing wrong is I should have used Zonal Statistics as Table not just zonal statistics.